# Longest way for all vertex

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

how can I optimalize this code?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Graph {
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
    void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);
public:
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    void DFS(int v);
};

Graph::Graph(int V) {
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) {
    adj[v].push_back(w);
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]) {
    visited[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";

    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if (!visited[*i])
            DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}

void Graph::DFS(int v) {
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
    DFSUtil(v, visited);
}

int main() {
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        g.DFS(i);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I mean, for now I calculate path for each vertex all over again. Well, it's very inefficient for many vertex, so my answer is: How can I rebuild this code such that I don't must calculate from zero

Answer (score 1):

Few habits to learn early in life.

1. passing big arguments by references. ( `bool& visited[]` )
2. deleting unused memory. (`delete visited`)
3. proper indentation always makes it better.

Here is the complete code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
    void DFSUtil(int v, bool& visited[]);
    public:
    Graph(int V);
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    void DFS(int v);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool& visited[])
{
    visited[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";
    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if (!visited[*i])
            DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}

void Graph::DFS(int v)
{
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;
    DFSUtil(v, visited);
    delete visited; // avoids memory leaks
}

int main()
{
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3, 3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        g.DFS(i);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Apart from these your code is very optimized possible.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really look like c++

1. Do not use `namespace std`
2. Use appropriate containers. If you want dynamic resizing, then `std::vector` if the size ist known to be static you can try `std::array`
3. Same goes for the list array you have. Why not just using a std::vector and be done with it. That way you do not have to handle memory at all.
4. Avoid assignments like`this->V = V` just because you are too lazy to think of a better name for your input argument.
5. You can add the assignment of loop variables inside the loop
6. If you use containers you can even use range based loops which simplify your code a lot.
7. constify input argumnents of functions that should not change.
8. Do you trust your users that much, that you do not check for valid input?

Together it should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class Graph
{
    int numVertices;
    std::vector<std::list<int> > adj;
    void DFSUtil(const int vertex, std::vector<bool> &visited);
public:
    Graph(const int vertices);
    void addEdge(const int vertex, const int weight);
    void DFS(const int vertex);
};

Graph::Graph(const int vertices)
{
    numVertices = vertices;
    adj = std::vector<std::list<int>>(vertices);
}

void Graph::addEdge(const int vertex, const int weight)
{
    adj[vertex].push_back(weigth);
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(const int vertex, std::vector<bool>& visited)
{
    visited[vertex] = true;
    std::cout << vertex << " ";
    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (auto visitedVertex : adj[v]) {
        if (!visited[visitedVertex]) {
            DFSUtil(visitedVertex, visited);
        }
    }
}

void Graph::DFS(const int vertex)
{
    std::vector<bool> visited(numVertices, false);
    DFSUtil(vertex, visited);
}

int main()
{
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 2);
    g.addEdge(2, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3, 3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        g.DFS(i);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```